# SSRS Passing values between list and subreport

Tags: reporting-services, subreport

So this is like my third SSRS question and I've only been looking at it for a day :S

This question may be a little sketchy as I'm still not up with the terminology.

Basically I have a list that is bound to a "Select" of SiteId's. Inside this list I have a sub report. The idea is to pass these SiteId's into the sub report one at a time to generate a report for each site Id.

But I can't figure out the expression required to pass this value in?

Way off the mark? or is there an answer to this question

Answer (score 2):

Look at the properties for the sub report (right click on the sub report and hit properties). In the properties dialog, there is a parameters tab where you can link parameters from the sub report to values from the parent report.  So, if you have subreport with a SiteID parameter, you can link that to the SiteID value from the list.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160348%28SQL.90%29.aspx

Comment: That's great, but I don't know how to link it to the SiteId value from the list any help on that would be appreciated

Comment: The SiteID must be a field in the dataset that is bound to the list.  As long as that is the case, on the parameters tab, there should be two columns with drop down lists.  One column allows you to select from the sub report parameters.  The other column allows you to select fields from the list.  Just select the SiteID parameter and field and that's it.  Then, for each record that displays in the list, the SiteID will be passed to the sub report and the report will be executed and rendered.

Comment: Oh man, foolish mistake, dragging and dropping not working out for me the sub report wasn't actually inside the list :( Now it is, it all makes sense, thanks!